# How can I use conditionals in a single-line Bash command?

Tags: bash, conditional-statements

My goal is to add an argument to a program being executed if a bash variable is existent, as so:

`bob -a some_arg (( if we have ${VAR} defined add '-b ${VAR}' as an argument ))`

I'd like to avoid something like:

```
if [[ -z ${VAR} ]]; then
    bob -a some_arg
else
    bob -a some_arg -b ${VAR}
fi
```

Although, it is the only option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using bash *parameter expansion* :

```
bob -a some_arg ${VAR:+-b "$VAR"}
```

Some good doc : http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe

And also `LESS=+/'Parameter Expansion' man bash

Comment: to test : `printf "%s\n" -a some_arg ${VAR:+..}`

Answer (score 1):

You could use an array for that (see [Arrays](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/arrays.html)):

```
args=( -a some_args )
if [ ... ] ; then
  args+=( -b "${VAR}" )
fi
bob "${args[@]}"
```

Comment: Hum... not sure that answers the question actually.